# Distube search no result

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem with my code, i try to code a discord music bot but if I play a song with soundcloud or youtbe link not all links work, only some link. That returns me song not found. I tried multiple things but none of them worked. I use distube for the bot because it can support youtube and soundcloud

Here is my code:

```js
const { DisTube } = require('distube')
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ]
})

const fs = require('fs')
const { SpotifyPlugin } = require('@distube/spotify')
const { SoundCloudPlugin } = require('@distube/soundcloud')
const { YtDlpPlugin } = require('@distube/yt-dlp')


const distube = new DisTube(client, {

    leaveOnStop: false,
    emitNewSongOnly: true,
    nsfw: true,
    emitAddSongWhenCreatingQueue: false,
    emitAddListWhenCreatingQueue: false,
    plugins: [new SoundCloudPlugin()],
  })
  
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("ONLINE")
})


client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    const prefix = "-"
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)

    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    if (args.shift().toLowerCase() === "play") {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return message.channel.send("Devi essere in un canale vocale")
        }

        const voiceChannelBot = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.type == "GUILD_VOICE" && x.members.has(client.user.id))
        if (voiceChannelBot && voiceChannel.id != voiceChannelBot.id) {
            return message.channel.send("Qualun'altro sta già ascoltando della musica")
        }

        let args = message.content.split(/\s+/)
        let query = args.slice(1).join(" ")

        if (!query) {
            return message.channel.send("Inserisci la canzone che vuoi ascoltare")
        }

        distube.play(message.member.voice.channel, args.join (" "), {
            member: message.member,
            textChannel: message.channel,
            message
        } )
    }
   
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    const prefix = "-"
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)

    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    if (args.shift().toLowerCase() === "pause") { 
        const song = distube.getQueue(message);
        if (!song) return message.channel.send("Non c'è nessuna canzone in riproduzione!");
        if (!song.paused) {
            distube.pause(message);
            message.channel.send('Canzone in pausa!');
        } else {
            message.channel.send('La canzone è già in pausa!');
        }       
    }
   
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    const prefix = "-"
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)

    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    if (args.shift().toLowerCase() === "stop") { 
        const song = distube.getQueue(message);
        if (!song) return message.channel.send("Non c'è nessuna canzone in riproduzione!");
        distube.stop(message);
        message.channel.send('Canzone fermata!');            
    }
   
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    const prefix = "-"
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)

    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    if (args.shift().toLowerCase() === "skip") { 
        const queue = distube.getQueue(message);
        if (!queue) return message.channel.send("Canzone successiva non presente");
                if (queue.songs.length <= 1) {
     message.channel.send("Canzone successiva non presente");}  
            else {
                distube.skip(message);}              
}
   
})


distube.on("playSong", (queue, song) => {
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Riproducendo canzone")
        .addFields({ name: "Canzone:", value: song.name })
    queue.textChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })  
})

distube.on("searchNoResult", (message, query) => {
    message.channel.send("Canzone non trovata")
})

distube.on("addSong", (queue, song) => {
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("Canzone aggiunta:")
    .addFields({ name: "Canzone:", value: song.name })
    queue.textChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })  
})


client.login("TOKEN")
```

I would the bot plays all links not only some

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.